# GetMessage and peek message of user32 getting Exception System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, console

i am newbie. i am getting this exception last 2 days and not get solved :(
 it runs fine in vs 2008 but when i execute exe file it gives Exception after some time

the exception is

```
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. at clienttesting.EventLoop.GetMessage(MSG& lpMsg, IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 wMsgFil terMin, UInt32 wMsgFilterMax) at clienttesting.EventLoop.Run() in D:\noman\windowsconsole\windowsconsole\Pr ogram.cs:line 196 at clienttesting.Program.Main() in D:\noman\windowsconsole\windowsconsole\Pro gram.cs:line 35
```

the code is

```
         public static void Run()
    {
        MSG msg = new MSG();

        sbyte ret;
        do
        {
            if ((ret = GetMessage(out msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0)) != -1)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("the mesaaeg" + msg.Message.ToString());
                if (msg.Message == WM_QUIT)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (ret == -1)
                {
                    break; //-1 indicates an error
                }
                else
                {

                    TranslateMessage(ref msg);

                    DispatchMessage(ref msg);
                }
            }
        } while (true);


    }
```

the Exception states

Comment: I'd have to say, if I found myself having to manually implement a windows message pump from C#, I'm doing something wrong. Why have you decided to pump messages?

Comment: Also, your outer `if` condition means that the `if(ret==-1)` can never be true.

Comment: i want to known user activities that what he is doing this is my task bro

Comment: before it i have done it with peekmessage but same exception occured  public static void Run()
        {
           
 MSG msg;


 while (true)
 {
  while (PeekMessage(ref msg, 0, 0, 0, PeekMessageOption.PM_REMOVE))
  {
   if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
   {
    break;
   }

   TranslateMessage(ref msg);
   DispatchMessage(ref msg);
  }
 }
}

Comment: You might do better to look at e.g. [Handling Messages in Console Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163417.aspx) which leverages all of the code that's already available in .NET Framework and means you only have to write managed code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been around for a long time, but I landed on this page while researching the same error. My scenario is a bit different, but hopefully this answer will help someone. I'm creating a .Net 6 console app, but I'm calling the same Win32 Api methods.

I'm using the [PInvoke.Win32 nuget package,](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PInvoke.Win32/0.7.104) that way I don't have to do all the *DllImports* manually.

My error was that I didn't use the [*address-of operator '&'*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/pointer-related-operators#address-of-operator-) when passing the first argument to the *GetMessage* method. If you [check out the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/window-messages), you will see the examples also use the '&' in front of the *msg* parameter.

I see you use the *out* and *ref* parameter modifiers when calling *GetMessage*, *TranslateMessage* and *DispatchMessage*. Have you tried using the address-of operator '&' in stead?

Here's an example of the relevant parts using the [new .Net 6 console template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates) and the [PInvoke.Win32 nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PInvoke.Win32/0.7.104):

```
using PInvoke;

unsafe
{
    User32.MSG msg;
    while (User32.GetMessage(&msg, IntPtr.Zero, User32.WindowMessage.WM_NULL, User32.WindowMessage.WM_NULL) > 0)   // synchonous call, will block the thread till a message is received
    {
        User32.TranslateMessage(&msg);
        User32.DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```